# postgresql - sql injection through regex and similar-to

Tags: regex, postgresql, sql-injection

I was told that there is a possibility of SQL injection when using `SIMILAR TO` in combination with `REGEX` in `POSTGRESQL`. I read the corresponding manual which says :

> Be wary of accepting regular-expression search patterns from hostile
>   sources. If you must do so, it is advisable to impose a statement
>   timeout.
>   [9.7. Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html)

However I did an extensive search but could not find a sample for this kind of attack. Could somebody please provide an example?

Comment: A quick web search yielded a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS) that describes the problem and has examples.

Comment: and where does the sql injection come into play? The question is about "sql injection through regex"!

Answer (score 0):

Using either `SIMILAR TO` or `REGEX` can create a vector for an SQL injection even when using PDO abstraction, if accepting unfiltered user input, which can lead to a [ReDOS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS).

For example (in PHP code), if you have:

```
$this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM items WHERE text SIMILIAR TO :searchpattern');
// OR
$this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM items WHERE text ~ :searchpattern');
$stmt->bindValue(':searchpattern', $_GET['searchpattern']);
```

Then if someone sends the searchpattern `([a-zA-Z]+)*$` (source: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS) you would cause a process on the server whose execution time would increase exponentially with the length of the string it would be testing (in this case, the DB field - `text`) if that string fails for example on the last character.